# How can I change the format date of a SharePoint list that was shared with me?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

This is a pre existing list that I was given access to.

I have over 800 rows of data that I would like to copy from an excel table however I am having issues with the date formatting.

The excel date is using UK format whereas the SharePoint site is using US format. I have tried to change the format on Excel to US but the value of the date itself remains UK. Is there another way I can do this as I am not able to paste all the rows of data without changing the dates to US format on the SharePoint list.

Thanks

I have tried to change the format on the Excel document however the value remains in UK format.